# How does request.parameters.next work in Vapor mechanism?

Tags: vapor

When using Vapor to build a API, always use a method to fetch a object,

`request.parameters.next(type.self)`

It seems a method to extract the url parameter, why it return the result from the database ? Could not found any clues from the framework's source code. How can I find the answer ? Thanks.

Comment: To understand it please take a look at `Parameter` protocol. When you conform you database model to `Parameter` you can return Future with that item from the database. That's why in your requests you can get an object from the database just by its ID in URL params.

Comment: @imike Follow your thought, should I find the database (I am using postgreSQL) which conform the Parameter protocol, and it will help me to know how it grab the data from it?

Comment: 99% that you already have a `User` model in your current Vapor project. If so then just add `extension User: Parameter {}` to conform this model to `Parameter` and then try to use it in some endpoint in your controller like this `router.get("test", User.parameter) { try $0.parameters.next(User.self) }` then try to call it like this http://localhost:8080/test/<USER_ID>

Comment: btw feel free to find me on Discord as `imike#3049` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This how `Parameter` protocol looks like

```swift
public protocol Parameter {
    associatedtype ResolvedParameter

    static var routingSlug: String { get }

    static func resolveParameter(_ parameter: String, on container: Container) throws -> ResolvedParameter
}
```

when you conform anything to `Parameter` you should implement this function

```swift
static func resolveParameter(_ parameter: String, on container: Container) throws -> ResolvedParameter
```

which should parse string parameter from URL and return some object as a result. And as `Parameter` is generic you can return any type you want.

Let's write an extension to conform `Date` to `Parameter`

```swift
extension Date: Parameter {
    public static func resolveParameter(_ parameter: String, on container: Container) throws -> Date {
        guard let timeIntervalSince1970 = TimeInterval(parameter) else {
            throw Abort(.notAcceptable, reason: "Unable to parse \"\(parameter)\" parameter")
        }
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeIntervalSince1970)
    }
}
```

`Parameter`'s method parses `String` parameter from URL and returns`Date`, but you also can return something else, e.g. `TimeInterval` since `Parameter` is generic protocol

```swift
extension Date: Parameter {
    public static func resolveParameter(_ parameter: String, on container: Container) throws -> TimeInterval {
        guard let timeIntervalSince1970 = TimeInterval(parameter) else {
            throw Abort(.notAcceptable, reason: "Unable to parse \"\(parameter)\" parameter")
        }
        return timeIntervalSince1970
    }
}
```

When you conform your Fluent model to `Parameter` it already have an implementation for `Parameter` protocol in its extensions, that's why you shouldn't declare `resolveParameter` function manually.

Let's take a look how it works if you declare `resolveParameter` method manually in e.g. `User` model

```swift
extension User {
    public static func resolveParameter(_ parameter: String, on container: Container) throws -> Future<User> {
        // e.g. User's primary key is UUID
        guard let id = UUID(parameter) else {
            throw Abort(.notAcceptable, reason: "Unable to parse \"\(parameter)\" into UUID")
        }
        // getting database connection from pool
        return container.requestPooledConnection(to: .psql).flatMap { conn in
            // querying user by provided primary key
            return User.query(on: conn)
                       .filter(\.id == id)
                       .first()
                       .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound, reason: "Unable to find user by provided primary key"))
                       .always {
                // will release connection in any case
                try? container.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .psql)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see you can implement `resolveParameter` to return anything you want.